# Where is the Trust setting in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

According to [Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/trust-settings?view=vs-2017), there is a setting in Visual Studio 2017 that deals with Trust for Files and Folders but I couldn't find it.
[image]

How do I find/enable this setting?

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Enterprice version 15.7.6

Comment: I found  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/trust-settings?view=vs-2017

Comment: @barlop I linked that in my question. May I know what your point is?

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2017 & 2019: Tools/Options:Environment/Trust Settings...
[image: VisualStudioTrustSettings]

I must say that knowing this hasn't helped me.  I use a share between a host machine and (a number of) VM(s) used for development and testing across different versions/editions of Windows.  There are still things I cannot do in trusted shared paths, so I've resorted to keeping multiple, local copies of source.  A bit ugly but understandable I suppose, given the bigger security picture :-(